# Bitlocker without TPM: does the USB drive have to remain in the laptop?

Tags: windows-7, disk-encryption, bitlocker

I'm using TrueCrypt to encrpyt my harddrive, but with the vague ending of this product, I want to switch to Bitlocker.

As I don't have a TPM chip in my laptop, I want to use a USB drive to authenticate.

Now my question is: when I startup my laptop the USB drive has to be present in my laptop I assume, but does it has to stay there after starting up?

The reason I ask is this: if it doesn't have to remain there, I can buy a very small USB drive that I can put on my keychain and only use to unlock; if however the USB drive has to remain on my laptop I wil not do this because my carkeys will be attached to my laptop the whole day ;-)

Comment: After the drive is unlocked it shouldn't be required.  It would only be required if the drive is locked again.

Comment: is " it shouldn't be" the same as " it isn't"?

Comment: no. I mean shouldn't or "should not". If I meant "is not" I would have said that instead.  I make a habit of saying exactly what I mean.